# How to change the div style when you move the mouse over another element in another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my personal project and i need to change div style which is my cursor (from width and height 10px to width and height 100px) when i'm hovering it on h1 element inside another div.

I tried

```
h1:hover ~ .cursor{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

and

```
h1:hover + .cursor{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

but it didn't work in this case. Do you know how to do it?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="mainHeader">
        <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="cursor"></div>

    <script src="js/cursor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,800&display=swap');

*, html{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    cursor: none;
}

.mainHeader{
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255), 255);
    font-weight: 800;
}

.cursor{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 200ms ease-out;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

h1:hover ~ .cursor{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

here is my js code responsible for following div with the mouse:

```
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.pageY - 5) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX - 5) + "px;");
});
```

The cursor works because when I changed the code so that the "~" works, everything was ok. 
I'm open to solutions in javascript.

Codepen version: https://codepen.io/Flayy/pen/vYBwzgE

Comment: Just a UX note - the easing of the cursor makes it feel laggy and is not nice.

Comment: You are right but that's personal project made for fun. But I agree 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class (or an id) on the H1 tag to be able to select it in the script, e.g.:

```
<h1 class="bigCursor">WELCOME</h1>
```

And in the script:

```
const bigCursor = document.querySelector('.bigCursor')
```

So change your 'mousemove' event function to a more flexible way to edit style:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
});
```

And add this to functions to respectively increase and decrease size of the cursor

```
bigCursor.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    cursor.style.width = "100px";
    cursor.style.height = "100px";
});

bigCursor.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    cursor.style.width = "10px";
    cursor.style.height = "10px";
});
```

At this point you may have realised that the cursor is not centered on the mouse, so add this line inside the `.cursor` CSS tag to fix this:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[Codepen version](https://codepen.io/jonatanlins/pen/ZEzNMaM)

Answer (score 0):

Hey in CSS you can `only change` the CSS properties of another element on hover if the element is a `child` or `adjacent` to the hovered element.

I moved your `cursor div` to be `adjacent` to the `H1 element` and added a `+` to your h1 hover css property:

CodePen: https://codepen.io/sudoxx2/pen/dybEqqY

Answer (score 0):

just write two functions one on mouseenter and second on mouseleave

```
document.getElementById(hoverElement).addEventListener("mouseenter",function(){
     document.getElementById(cursorElement).style.width = "100px"
     document.getElementById(cursorElement).style.height = "100px"})
```

and add another on mouseleave

```
document.getElementById(hoverElement).addEventListener("mouseleave",function(){
     document.getElementById(cursorElement).style.width = "10px"
     document.getElementById(cursorElement).style.height = "10px"})
```